# ng-bootstrap and Angular 6: Can't resolve all parameters for NgbModalRef: (?,?,?,?)

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

Has anyone used ng-bootstrap and come across the following error with angular 6

[image: console window]

I have included

```
imports:[NgbModule]
providers: [NgbModule, NgbModalRef]
```

in the app.module.ts file

inside my ts component file i have imported

```
import { NgbModal, NgbModalRef } from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";

 constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        private modalService: NgbModal,
        private activeModel: NgbModalRef,
        private readonly resourceService: ResourceService,
        private readonly authService: AuthService,
        private readonly userService: UserService,
        private readonly competitionService: CompetitionService){}

open(content: any, modal?: ICompetition) {
        if (modal == undefined) {
            this.competitionFrm.setValue({
                competitionKey: null,
                centre: this.user.Centre,
                programme: "",
                competitionName: ""
            });
            this.activeModel = this.modalService.open(content,{ ariaLabelledBy: "modal-basic-title", backdrop: "static", keyboard: false });
            this.activeModel.result.then((result) => {
                    this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
                },
                    (reason) => {
                        this.closeResult = `Dismissed with: ${reason}`;
                    });
        } else {
            this.competitionFrm.setValue({
                competitionKey: modal.competitionKey,
                centre: modal.centre,
                programme: modal.programme,
                competitionName: modal.competitionName
            });
        }
    }

saveDetails(model: any): void {
        this.competitionService.save(model).subscribe(
            data => {
                if (data.Successful === false) {
                    this.modelMsg = data.Information;
                } else {
                    this.msg = data.Information;
                    this.getCompetitions();
                    this.activeModel.close();
                }

            },
            error => this.msg = <any>error);
    }
```

does anyone have any knowledge as to the error that is being displayed in the browsers console window. I have seen some other issues from a while ago saying this was solved back in 2017 however the issue still seems to be there.

The purpose for this is to close the open modal from inside the save function.

Many thanks in advance

Lewis

UPDATE: app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { CommonModule, APP_BASE_HREF } from "@angular/common";
import { MatIconModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatSelectModule, MatDialogModule, } from "@angular/material";
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgbModule, NgbActiveModal, NgbModalRef} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';


import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { FooterComponent } from "./components/footer/footer.component";
import { HeaderComponent } from "./components/header/header.component";
import { NavBarComponent } from "./components/NavBar/navbar.component";
import { HomeComponent } from "./components/home/home.component";
import { AccountManagementComponent } from "./components/accountManagement/accountManagement.component";
import { CompetitionManagementComponent } from "./components/competitionManagement/competitionManagement.component";

import { appRoutingModule } from "./app.routing";
import { UserService } from "./Service/user.service";
import { LoginService } from "./Service/login.service";
import { AuthService } from "./Service/auth.service";
import { ResourceService } from "./Service/resource.service";
import { CompetitionService } from "./Service/competition.service";


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
      AppComponent,
      FooterComponent,
      HeaderComponent,
      NavBarComponent,
      HomeComponent,
      AccountManagementComponent,
      CompetitionManagementComponent
  ],
    imports: [
      NgbModule.forRoot(),
      BrowserModule,
      appRoutingModule,
      MatIconModule,
      MatFormFieldModule,
      MatSelectModule,
      MatDialogModule,
      ReactiveFormsModule,
      FormsModule,
      CommonModule,
      BrowserAnimationsModule,
      HttpClientModule
  ],
    providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' }, UserService, LoginService, AuthService, ResourceService, CompetitionService, NgbModule, NgbModalRef],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    entryComponents: [AccountManagementComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Can you post your app.module? This seems like a dependency issue setting up ng bootstrap

Comment: In your app.module's imports, you should try using `NgbModule.forRoot()` as suggested in [NgBootstrap's installation guide](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started).

Comment: Did you add it to entryComponents?
https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples#component

Comment: Everything is in place @canpan14 I have added the app.module to the question

Comment: @undefinedMayNotBeNull I have been searching for the information on the entryComponents and I don't seem to be able to see it in the documentation link you provided. I know angular material mentions that you need to add it to entry components to create a catalog. It still throws the same error regarding parameters being missing.

Comment: Which one is the component in question? `AccountManagementComponent`?

Comment: @undefinedMayNotBeNull its the `CompetitionManagementComponent` component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the solution to this is not to use `NgbModalRef` but to use `NgbActiveModal` with the suggestions that the guys above have suggested.

Within the `app.module.ts` file you need to ensure that all components that contain a modal are within the `entryComponents` options and `NgbModule.forRoot()` in the `imports` options.

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        NgbModule.forRoot()
    ],
    entryComponents: [
        AccountManagementComponent, 
        CompetitionManagementComponent
    ]
})
```

Within the component you need to import NgbActiveModal

```
import {NgbModal, NgbActiveModal} from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";
```

and then create a variable

```
activeModal: NgbActiveModal;
```

Create a function that will act as your open()

```
open(content: any) {
    this.activeModal = this.modalService.open(content,{ ariaLabelledBy: "modal-basic-title", backdrop: "static", keyboard: false });
}
```

In our case we have a form in the modal so this needs to save and then if the save is successful it will close the modal and display a msg on the main page.

```
save(model: any): void {
        this.dbService.save(model).subscribe(
            data => {
                if (data.Successful === false) {
                    this.modelMsg = data.Information;
                } else {
                    this.msg = data.Information;
                    this.activeModal.close();
                }

            },
            error => this.msg = <any>error);
    }
```

I hope this helps others that come across this issue.